# Difference between "art exhibition" and "art fair"

Tags: word-choice, differences

What is the difference between *art exhibition* and *art fair*? It seems both show something to an audience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exhibition denotes the idea of "**showing**" whereas "fair" may connote **showing, selling and entertainment** together.

Answer (score 2):

Works of art are shown at both an [exhibition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/exhibition) and a [fair](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/fair_8), but this is for the purpose of selling them in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

An **art exhibition** is an event in which works of art are shown to the public. Sometimes there is an entrance fee; sometimes not. Sometimes the works are for sale (a *selling exhibition*); sometimes not. Generally the works on show are connected by some kind of theme: by one artist, a group of artists, on a similar subject, from a similar time period or place, etc, and the whole exhibition is organised by a single curator or curatorial team to give a particular perspective.

An art exhibition might be held by a state museum or institution (called an *art museum* in the US but *public art gallery* in the UK), by a privately owned gallery, by an auction house looking to sell the work, or some other body. Major institutions like the National Gallery in London, the Louvre in Paris, Tate in Britain, etc, hold exhibitions: the [National Gallery](https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/exhibitions) in 2022-23 is holding single-artist shows of Raphael and Winslow Homer, major exhibitions accompanied by a substantial catalog, talks, and other events. But a small exhibition may be held in a bar, restaurant, foyer of an office building, or some other place used for other purposes, without any of the same art historical paraphernalia.

In contrast, an **art fair** is much like a trade fair, book fair, or trade show. A large number of exhibitioners involved in the art world rent stalls: galleries use it to sell art and promote themselves as businesses that buy and sell art, while other companies providing specialized services to the art world may also attend. The purpose is not to look at art for education or entertainment: it is aimed at art professionals and people looking to buy art and establish professional contacts, although students and other people may go along for a look.

Rather than having a single curator who selects works on artistic merit and relevance to the theme of the show, space in art fairs is rented out by the organiser to galleries, who then choose what to show. Perhaps the most famous is [Art Basel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Basel), held in Switzerland and several other world cities; [here is a Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/neloliviawaga/2022/06/16/the-best-of-art-basel-2022/) discussing its status as a leading art market and some of the high value sales, including a $40 million Louise Bourgeois sculpture. This sort of high value sale wouldn't happen at most art exhibitions. There are also a lot of smaller art fairs held in public halls and other venues, where artists and galleries can rent a table or stall and sell their work.

There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_exhibition), although it also discusses art fairs as a subtype of exhibition. It's probably simpler to view them as separate things, though.

Various other terms are sometimes used (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_exhibition)): an exhibition is sometimes called an *exposition* or similar in the US; in both US and UK, the term "art show" is sometimes used informally for an exhibition, particularly a smaller one, although it has a wider meaning and is sometimes used by art fairs.

In summary:

Art exhibition: aimed at general public; small number of curators decide what's shown; usually themed e.g. to single artist or time period; in bigger exhibitions a focus on art history and education; works may or may not be for sale.

Art fair: similar to other businesses' trade fair; aimed at professionals in the art world and/or art buyers; anyone who rents a stall can show what they like; multiple galleries and artists showing; no overall theme or organising principle; focus on selling art and establishing professional contacts; generally commercial in nature.